# docusign - adding tabs to the document using API: It only adds signhere tab and ignores all other

Tags: anchor, docusignapi

I am trying to add dateSingedTab, fullNameTab,signHereTab to my document. When I send the document, docusign is only adding the signHereTab and ignoring other tabs. Here is my xml. Can you please help.

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
<emailSubject>API Call for adding signature request to document and sending</emailSubject>
 <status>sent</status>
            <documents>
            <document>
                <documentId>1</documentId>
                <name>documentName</name>
            </document>
            </documents>
            <recipients>
            <signers>
            <signer>
                <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                <email>custEmail</email>
                <name>recipientNameCust</name>
                <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>
            <tabs>        
    <dateSignedTabs>
    <dateSignedTab>
        <anchorString>SIGNED on behalf of the Customer</anchorString>
        <anchorXOffset>100</anchorXOffset>
        <anchorYOffset>300</anchorYOffset>
        <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>false</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
        <anchorUnits>Pixels</anchorUnits>
        <documentId>1</documentId>
        <recipientId>1</recipientId>
        <tabLabel>Date Signed</tabLabel>
        <name>Date Signed</name>
      </dateSignedTab>
      </dateSignedTabs>
    <fullNameTabs>
    <fullNameTab>
      <anchorString>SIGNED on behalf of the Customer</anchorString>
      <anchorXOffset>100</anchorXOffset>
      <anchorYOffset>100</anchorYOffset>
      <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>false</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
      <anchorUnits>Pixels</anchorUnits>
      <documentId>1</documentId>
      <recipientId>1</recipientId>
      <tabLabel>Full Name</tabLabel>
      <name>Full Name</name>
    </fullNameTab>
    </fullNameTabs>
            <signHereTabs>
            <signHere>
               <anchorString>SIGNED on behalf of the Customer</anchorString>
               <anchorXOffset>0</anchorXOffset>
               <anchorYOffset>50</anchorYOffset>
               <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>false</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
               <anchorUnits>Pixels</anchorUnits>
               <documentId>1</documentId>
               <recipientId>1</recipientId>
               <tabLabel>Sign Here</tabLabel>
               <name>Sign Here</name>
            </signHere>
            </signHereTabs>
            </tabs>
            </signer>
            </signers>
            </recipients></envelopeDefinition>
```

I got the tags wrong in above xml. I corrected them and they work fine. dateSignedTab is not correct, it should be dateSigned. Also fullNameTab is not correct, it should be fullName.
Please ignore this post.

Comment: You need to use the docusignAPI tag for development/api questions, not the general docusign tab.  The right people will see it with docusignAPI.  Anyways, I think I see your issue, it's with your tab names.  I'll post an answer shortly...

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the `tabs` part of the inside tab names.  For instance, for dateSigned tabs the `<xml>` nodes need to look like this:

```
<dateSignedTabs>
    <dateSigned>
    ...
    </dateSigned>
</dateSignedTabs>
```

Same thing with your other tabs... the full name tabs need to be setup like this:

```
<fullNameTabs>
    <fullName>
    ...
    </fullName>
</fullNameTabs>
```

Give that a try and it should work.