# Unable to add Date Signed field with Docusign PHP SDK

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am using the PHP SDK from https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client, and I am attempting to add a Date Signed field to the document. I am successfully creating an envelope, adding a Signer, and sending the Envelope. But I can't figure out what I'm missing with the Date Signed field.

I have searched high and low for an example of adding it, as well as looking at the API docs. I feel like I am missing some method that actually places the field or 'tab' on the document and need a pointer in the right direction. I have found things such as 
[this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859057/docusign-adding-tabs-to-the-document-using-api-it-only-adds-signhere-tab-and)
which showed me what properties I needed to set on the DateSigned object, but doesn't help me figure out the PHP methods I need to call.

I'm making a wrapper class for our project, so if you can ignore that bit I will share the code I do have, for adding a Signature Field, then my attempt at adding a Date Signed field for a given Signer. I am confused what I'm missing that will actually place it on the document. I omitted the code where I actually called these methods but the Envelope does send - just no Date Signed field.

Thanks much

```
function addSigner($signerName, $signerEmail, $xPos, $yPos, $documentId = 1, $documentPage = 1)
{
     $index = count($this->signers);
     $this->signers[$index] = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer();
     $this->signers[$index]->setName($signerName);
     $this->signers[$index]->setEmail($signerEmail);
     $this->signers[$index]->setRecipientId((string)$index + 1);
     $this->sigFields[$index] = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere();
     $this->sigFields[$index]->setXPosition($xPos);
     $this->sigFields[$index]->setYPosition($yPos);
     $this->sigFields[$index]->setDocumentId($documentId);
     $this->sigFields[$index]->setPageNumber($documentPage);
     $this->sigFields[$index]->setRecipientId((string)$index + 1);
     $this->sigTabs[$index] = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
     $this->sigTabs[$index]->setSignHereTabs(array($this->sigFields[$index]));
     $this->signers[$index]->setTabs($this->sigTabs[$index]);

     return $index;  // signerid
}

function addSignerDate($signerId, $xPos, $yPos, $documentId = 1)
{
     $index = count($this->dateSignedFields);
     $this->dateSignedFields[$index] = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\DateSigned();

     // the date should always be on the same page as the signature
     $pageNumber = $this->sigFields[$signerId]->getPageNumber();
     $this->dateSignedFields[$index]->setPageNumber($pageNumber);
     $this->dateSignedFields[$index]->setDocumentId($documentId);
     $this->dateSignedFields[$index]->setRecipientId($signerId);
     $this->dateSignedFields[$index]->setName('Date Signed');
     $this->dateSignedFields[$index]->setTabLabel('Date Signed');
     $this->dateSignedFields[$index]->setXPosition($xPos);
     $this->dateSignedFields[$index]->setYPosition($yPos);

    // EDIT - I added this bit but still no Date Signed. Probably the right track though. 
     $this->dateSignedTabs[$index] = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
     $this->dateSignedTabs[$index]->setDateSignedTabs(array($this->dateSignedFields[$index]));
     $this->dateSignedFields[$index]->setTabId($this->dateSignedTabs[$index]);

     return $index;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's how I fixed it. I changed to only having one Tabs array - no separate one for the Date Signed fields. The Tabs object holds different types of Tabs, so we use the same one for both fields.

```
function addSigner($signerName, $signerEmail, $xPos, $yPos, $documentId = 1, $documentPage = 1)
{
    $index = count($this->signers);
    $this->signers[$index] = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer();
    $this->signers[$index]->setName($signerName);
    $this->signers[$index]->setEmail($signerEmail);
    $this->signers[$index]->setRecipientId((string)$index + 1);
    $this->sigFields[$index] = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere();
    $this->sigFields[$index]->setXPosition($xPos);
    $this->sigFields[$index]->setYPosition($yPos);
    $this->sigFields[$index]->setDocumentId($documentId);
    $this->sigFields[$index]->setPageNumber($documentPage);
    $this->sigFields[$index]->setRecipientId((string)$index + 1);
    $this->sigTabs[$index] = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
    $this->sigTabs[$index]->setSignHereTabs(array($this->sigFields[$index]));

    return $index;
}

function addSignerDate($signerId, $xPos, $yPos, $documentId = 1)
{
    $index = count($this->dateSignedFields);
    $this->dateSignedFields[$index] = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\DateSigned();

    // the date should always be on the same page as the signature
    $pageNumber = $this->sigFields[$signerId]->getPageNumber();

    $this->dateSignedFields[$index]->setPageNumber($pageNumber);
    $this->dateSignedFields[$index]->setDocumentId($documentId);
    $this->dateSignedFields[$index]->setRecipientId($signerId);
    $this->dateSignedFields[$index]->setName('Date Signed');
    $this->dateSignedFields[$index]->setTabLabel('Date Signed');
    $this->dateSignedFields[$index]->setXPosition($xPos);
    $this->dateSignedFields[$index]->setYPosition($yPos);

    $this->sigTabs[$signerId]->setDateSignedTabs(array($this->dateSignedFields[$index]));

    return $index;
}
```

Then I add them to the document later in my SendEnvelope method:

```
foreach($this->signers as $signerId => $signer)
{
    $this->signers[$signerId]->setTabs($this->sigTabs[$signerId]);
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for posting a solution.  Can you accept your own answer for the benefit of others?  Thx

Comment: It makes me wait two days, but I will then.